# CSS style not reverting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set a CSS property back and forth using JavaScript depending on its value.

The class name `menu` is set to be hidden on page load. When I call the function to set it to visible it is successful. However, when I call it again to change it back it doesn't set it to hidden. It is seen as always set to visible.

```
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
if (menu.style.visibility = 'hidden') {
  menu.style.visibility = 'visible';
  console.log('visible'); // always shows this.
} else {
  menu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  console.log('hidden'); // doesn't get to here when .menu is visible.
}
```

I am confused as to why it can do the first but not the second. I have tried using a `else if` condition:

```
else if (menu.style.visibility = 'visible')
```

I also tried using the `setAttribute` method but it's always the same outcome.

I need to be able to switch back and forth.

Comment: why don't you use jQuery??

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're using a single equals sign in your conditions. This doesn't check if the visibility equals "visible", it actually assigns the string "visible" to the visibility (or at least tries to). Use two or three equals signs for a condition to check equality. Three equals signs is the preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript by using `=` you assign a value to something BUT if you use `==` you are checking if something is equal to something else.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
if (menu.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
  menu.style.visibility = 'visible';
  console.log('visible'); // always shows this.
} else {
  menu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  console.log('hidden'); // doesn't get to here when .menu is visible.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use below condition

```
if (menu.style.visibility == 'hidden') //change ==
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it has resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional isn't valid. You're actually setting the value in the if statement.

```
if (menu.style.visibility = 'hidden') // this sets the value
```

It should be this:

```
if (menu.style.visibility == 'hidden') // this compares the value
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your if statement. So if you change the single equality to a double equal sign: `==`, your code should work:

like:

```
if (menu.style.visibility == 'hidden')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will toggle the visibility of a div on your page.

```js
function togglediv() {
  var div = document.getElementById("menu");
  div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="togglediv('menu')">Toggle div</button>
<div id="menu">div</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax for comparing is wrong you need to use `==` while comparing any field in javascript so just do :

```
if (menu.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
  menu.style.visibility = 'visible';
  console.log('visible'); // always shows this.
} else {
menu.style.visibility == 'hidden';
console.log('hidden'); // doesn't get to here when .menu is visible.
}
```